# How to put minorticks on both the sub plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am having two sub plots in the figure.  How to add the minor ticks on both x and y axis of both the sub plots?
   Also, How can I put the y-label for the right sub plot on the right side of the y axis?
Can you please answer the above questions?
   The piece of code is as follows:

```
# Open the figure to plot the Gain variations for this frequencies
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(121) # To show the ascending order
plt.xlabel ('RF Input Power (dBm)', fontsize = 'smaller')
plt.ylabel ('Gain (dB)', fontsize = 'smaller')
tx = plt.title('Gain Vs Ascending RFInput for ' + str(measuredFrequencyUnderTest) + 'MHz', fontsize = 'smaller')
plt.minorticks_on()

ay = plt.subplot(122, xlim = [rfInputMax, rfInputMin], ylim = [-18.0, 30.0]) # To show the descending order
plt.xlabel ('RF Input Power (dBm)', fontsize = 'smaller')
plt.ylabel ('Gain (dB)', fontsize = 'smaller', horizontalalignment = 'left') 
ty = plt.title('Gain Vs Descending RF Input for '+ str(measuredFrequencyUnderTest)+ 'MHz', fontsize = 'smaller')
```

This code is inserting the minorticks only on the first sub plot.  Even if I have the command "plt.minorticks_on" for both sub-plots, they are not appearing on both the sub-plots.

I need your advice on that.

Thanking you
Gopi

Comment: What graphics library? What have you tried so far? Show some code, please. Otherwise nobody will know what you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have added the piece of code in the first question.

Comment: Still no idea what graphics library you're using.

Comment: @Andrea: Edited tags, maybe it will attract someone who can answer.

Comment: Also, use string formatting instead of doing 'somestring' + str(var) + 'otherstring'. (-> 'somestring %d otherstring' % var).

Answer (score 2):

Just call `minorticks_on()` on the axes and not on the `pyplot` object:

```
ax = plt.subplot(121)
#....
ax.minorticks_on()

ay = plt.subplot(122, ...)
#...
ay.minorticks_on()
```

Comment: Thanks Andrea for the answer.  But for the ax subplot it is working. But for ay the minor ticks are not seen with your approach. I might be doing still something wrong. Can you please help me?  Gopi

Comment: Hi, I tried the code I posted and it works.. Can you update the question with a minimum example that doesn't work? Please remove all the extraneous variables and just leave a plot with two subplots. (Maybe in this process you'll discover what is your error :) )